# Using Jquery ajax call in different Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, return-value

I have a problem with this function

```
function readComm(){
    $.post("something.php", {read:"read"}, function(data){
        retVal = $.trim(data).toString();
        console.log(retVal);
        return retVal;
    });
}
```

It should call php file, and read some value from a text file. It does that as it should, and prints it on my console correctly, from a function. The problem is when I want to use that value in another function. It says that the value is undefined. retVal is a global variable, so that's not a problem.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: `$.post()` is asynchronous by default. Perhaps you are trying to use the value of `retVal` before it is set in the above callback.

Comment: This looks like yet another dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: I've managed to solve this issue by calling a different function from inside of post function. And that is the only way to transfer that value to another function. Thank you anyway!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should change your angle to using callback functions approach, because what you do with `$.post` is asynchronous:

```
function readComm(callback){
    $.post("something.php", {read:"read"}, function(data){
        retVal = $.trim(data).toString();
        console.log(retVal);
        callback(retVal);
    });
}

function nextStep(retVal){
    alert(retVal);
}
readComm(nextStep);
```

what it does is actually taking the next step using `nextStep` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing something like this:

```
readComm();
alert(retVal);
```

Then that won't work because `readComm` is an asynchronous function. Anything that relies on the `retVal` MUST be either inside that function, called by it, or sufficiently deferred (for instance, a function called by an element that is only added by the asynchronous call)